# React useState causing "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.." error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React/Node and working on a learning project. It's a platform that connects users (freelancers) with nonprofit companies. When a user logs in, they can go to the UserConnections page to view all the companies they connected with.

This is working correctly, but I also get the warning `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.` Also when I visit this component, the command line starts spitting out connection messages extremely fast endlessly.

I think the problem is coming from this `useEffect` that is used in the UserConnections component. This block of code was a pain to write, and it took the help of multiple people on here to write it. I'm hesitant to touch it.

```
useEffect(() => {        
      const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
      Promise.all(comps).then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));
    }    
  }, [connections]);
```

I tried to rewrite it like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
    if (isMounted) {
      Promise.all(comps).then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));
    }
    return () => { isMounted = false };        
  }, [connections]);
```

But that didn't change anything at all.

How can I change this code to avoid the memory leak without affecting the intended use of this function? Below is the code for this component. Thank you for any help.

**UserConnections**

```
function UserConnections() {
  const { currentUser, connectionHandles } = useContext(UserContext);
  const connections = currentUser.connections.concat(connectionHandles);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
    Promise.all(comps).then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));
  }, [connections]);

  if (!companies || companies.length == 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You have no connections</p>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {companies && companies.map(c => (
          <CompanyCard
            key={c.companyHandle}
            companyHandle={c.companyHandle}
            companyName={c.companyName}
            country={c.country}
            numEmployees={c.numEmployees}
            shortDescription={c.shortDescription}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it ***almost*** right in your rewrite (great job!) - the `isMounted` check needs to go inside the `then`.

instead of:

```js
    if (isMounted) {
      Promise.all(comps).then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));
    }
```

you write it like this:

```js
      Promise.all(comps).then(comps => isMounted && setCompanies(comps));
```

It's also just a warning. You should fix it, yes, but it's not crazy critical.

EDIT:

The infinite loop problem:

```js
const connections = currentUser.connections.concat(connectionHandles);
```

connections changes everytime you re-render your component (call `setCompanies`) so the `useEffect` reference changes. The way to fix it is to use `connectionHandles` and `currentUser` as dependencies of the effect, and move `connections` inside of the effect like:

```
function UserConnections() {
  const { currentUser, connectionHandles } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    // move connections inside the effect
    const connections = currentUser.connections.concat(connectionHandles);
    const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
    Promise.all(comps).then((comps => isMounted && setCompanies(comps)));
    return () => { isMounted = false };
  }, [currentUser,connectionHandlers]);


...
```

Comment: Thank you. This got rid of the warning, but in Bash, when I visit UserConnections, I can still see API calls firing off on repeat indefinitely. Is this safe to ignore? Sounds like my code is in an infinite loop.

Comment: @bourne2077 - Yes your code is in an infinite loop and no it's not safe to ignore. See my edit on how to fix it.